# Why do I get dereferencing pointer errors?

Tags: c, pointers, byte, bit

I'm currently doing a C programme which requires the use of pointers, which I'm not great at.
I'm currently getting 4 errors which all say 'dereferencing pointer to incomplete type' and I don't know why.

Here is an example of how I set up my pointers and where I get the errors.

```
struct myset
{
    unsigned char *vector;
    int size;
    int size_in_bytes;
    int size_in_bits;
};

struct myset* set_new(int size)
{
    int i;
    struct myset* s;
    s= malloc (sizeof (struct myset));
    s->vector=malloc(sizeof(char)*(size/(sizeof(char)*8))+1);
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        s->vector[i]=0;
    }
    s->size_in_bits=size;
    s->size_in_bytes=(size/(sizeof(char)))+1;
    return s;
};
```

and I get an error whenever I try to reference the pointer, for example in this function.

```
void bitset_intersect(struct bitset * dest, struct bitset * src1, struct bitset * src2)
{
    int maxSize = dest -> size_in_bits;
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i = 0; i<maxSize; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<maxSize; j++)
        {
        if(bitset_lookup(src1, i) == bitset_lookup(src2, j))
          {
              bitset_add(dest,i);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is in the line `int maxSize = dest -> size_in_bits;`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where is the definition of `struct bitset`? I only see the definition of `struct myset`.

Comment: `s->vector=malloc(sizeof(char)*(size/(sizeof(char)*8))+1);` should be `s->vector=malloc(size+1);`.

Comment: You don't show where you call `bitset_intersect`

Comment: sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be 1 by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Without the function call, its slightly hard to tell if you are passing the right values as parameters.

If you are getting an error while trying to reference the pointer, then check the function call to make sure you are passing the address correctly. Doing so would remove this error.

Both *dest and *src should have address that is being passed into it since both are from the same struct bitset.